# How to set control properties in constructor (problems with Designer)

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, custom-controls, overriding

I am trying to inherit from the ToolStripLabel:

```
public class SeparatorLabel : ToolStripLabel
{
    public SeparatorLabel() : base()
    {
        Margin = new Padding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        Text = "ABC";
    }
}
```

However, when I place such a control on the form, the `Text` property is taken from the value entered in the designer's property grid.

This is, of course, expected, since my constructor gets called before the property grid's properties are set (form's `InitializeComponent()`), so my values get overwritten.

The question is - **what is the standard practice** to achieve such behavior when inheriting from existing controls?

The way I did implement it was to override the `Text` property to include an empty setter, and when I want to update the control's `Text`, I set the `base.Text` manually:

```
public class SeparatorLabel : ToolStripLabel
{
    public SeparatorLabel() : base()
    {
        Margin = new Padding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        base.Text = "ABC";
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public override string Text
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Text;
        }
        set { }
    }
}
```

This works but I am not sure if that's the best practice. Is there any more conventional way to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't compile since your constructor is different than your class.

You can also look at the [DesignerSerializationVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerserializationvisibility.aspx) attribute, and set it to `Hidden`.

```
public SeparatorLabel() {
  base.Margin = new Padding(5, 0, 5, 0);
}

[Browsable(false)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new Padding Margin {
  get { return base.Margin; }
  set {
    throw new Exception("This property is read only.");
  }
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the error in my example (I wasn't directly copying from my code, hence the invalid constructor name).